# Hands-on experience configuring a virtual network

Tags: vpn, routing, amazon-vpc

I want to understand the details of how a VPC or virtual overlay network is setup. I'll personally learn it best if I get some hands-on experience doing it.

I was wondering if I can rent a few machines on EC2. I know EC2 will put them inside a default AWS VPC. But the practice exercise I was thinking to do is to partition these EC2 VMs into a couple of virtual network that I configure myself and then also establish routing between them to learn how to configure routing, gateways etc.

Do you think all this is possible? Is there a tutorial I can follow to learn how to setup Virtual private networks manually?

Comment: Learning AWS VPC will teach you how to use AWS

Comment: I don't think you would learn much about the workings of VPCs on AWS or Azure. They just give you forms to fill in, and the VPCs appear magically. Instead, find documentation of technologies like VXLAN or GRE and set up a VXLAN/GRE networks among two or more virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

AWS and Azure both have a free tier where you can practice to your heart’s content.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really know what linux commands to run to setup the routing, gateways etc. though. Is there some book/article/documentation somewhere how to do it? For learning this?

Comment: Search the internet for "network overlay technologies". There are several, such as VXLAN (most popular right now?), GRE, Geneve, even VLAN. For example, a random page I found is a [VXLAN lab description](http://ce.sc.edu/cyberinfra/workshops/Material/SDN/Lab%205%20-Configuring%20VXLAN%20to%20Provide%20Network%20Traffic%20Isolation.pdf) from the university of South Carolina.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the free tier. There's no notification when you leave the free tier and start paying money for things. But AWS and Azure have plenty of *cheap* stuff you can use, which shouldn't cost much. Treat the free tier as a little sign-up present, rather than a guarantee of free anything.